# How to put a RadioButton label in single line

Tags: android, android-layout

In my app radio button with lable 'Colour' is shown in two lines.  How to fix in single line.  Please follow my xml.  I used this xml in android popup window

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:id="@+id/popup"
        android:background="@android:color/black">

         <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:textStyle="bold"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                android:text="Online Control"/>

        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:layout_margin="1dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:background="@color/colorAccent">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Mode"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/oc_rg_mode"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/oc_mono"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Mono"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:buttonTint="#0000ff"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/oc_color"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:buttonTint="#0000ff"
                    android:text="Colour"/>
            </RadioGroup>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Flip"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

            <RadioGroup
                android:id="@+id/oc_rg_flip"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="horizontal">

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/oc_flip_set"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:text="Set"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:buttonTint="#0000ff"/>

                <RadioButton
                    android:id="@+id/oc_flip_reset"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:textSize="15dp"
                    android:text="Reset"
                    android:maxLines="1"
                    android:buttonTint="#0000ff"/>
            </RadioGroup>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Brightness"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/oc_brightness"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/MySeekBarTheme"
                android:max="255"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Contrast"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/oc_contrast"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/MySeekBarTheme"
                android:max="8"/>

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="Saturation"
                android:textSize="15dp"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

            <SeekBar
                android:id="@+id/oc_saturation"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:theme="@style/MySeekBarTheme"
                android:max="8"/>

            <LinearLayout
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:padding="10dp">

                <Button
                    android:id="@+id/oc_close"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="35dp"
                    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
                    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                    android:text="Close"/>
            </LinearLayout>
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

[image]

Comment: try to put the radiogroup in a horizental scrollview,

Comment: can you show a screenshot for the same

Comment: you are on right track just set `match_parent` to the width of your parent layout.

Comment: @Riskhan check my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this you will get your required result, I have checked this layout in different screen sizes too it works well. And also I have formatted your layout for you :P

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center_vertical|left"
        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:padding="5dp"
        android:textSize="20dp"
        android:text="Online Control"/>

</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_margin="1dp"
    android:paddingTop="10dp"
    android:paddingLeft="10dp"
    android:paddingRight="10dp"
    android:background="@color/colorAccent">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Mode"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/oc_rg_mode"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/oc_mono"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="center|start"
            android:text="Mono"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:buttonTint="#0000ff"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:textSize="15dp"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/oc_color"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="center|start"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:buttonTint="#0000ff"
            android:text="Color"/>
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Flip"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/oc_rg_flip"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="2">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/oc_flip_set"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:text="Set"
            android:layout_weight="0.8"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:buttonTint="#0000ff"/>

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/oc_flip_reset"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1.2"
            android:gravity="center|start"
            android:textSize="15sp"
            android:text="Reset"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:buttonTint="#0000ff"/>
    </RadioGroup>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Brightness"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/oc_brightness"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/MySeekBarTheme"
        android:max="255"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Contrast"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/oc_contrast"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/MySeekBarTheme"
        android:max="8"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Saturation"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"/>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/oc_saturation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/MySeekBarTheme"
        android:max="8"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:padding="10dp">

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/oc_close"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="35dp"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:text="Close"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: you will have to play with weights, textsizes and fonts if you want your layout to be shown in that fixed sizes

Comment: Yes.  You are right!  Thanks Bro.  Your solution is worked

Comment: @Riskhan glad that it helped. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2):

Add `android:lines="1"` in `RadioButton`

```
<RadioGroup
        android:id="@+id/oc_rg_mode"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/oc_mono"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:buttonTint="#0000ff"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:lines="1"
            android:text="Mono"
            android:textSize="15dp" />

        <RadioButton
            android:id="@+id/oc_color"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:buttonTint="#0000ff"
            android:lines="1"
            android:text="Colour "
            android:textSize="15dp" />
    </RadioGroup>
```

Comment: Hi bro.  But 'r' is missing in radio button label

Comment: Either u show everything or show in multiple lines. On other hand u may adjust font sizes and spaces around for better experience.

Comment: Thanks Bro.  I go with Umair

Comment: maxLines and lines will have same impact here.